# Unique Identifier for scheduling notifications, Swift 3 iOS 10

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, unnotificationrequest

I am scheduling notifications with Unique Identifiers so I don't have to make a new String for each notification. This all works well for scheduling but the problem lies in trying to cancel them.

This is my code for scheduling notifications...

```
let notifIdentifier = TaskManager.notification2.userInfo.description as String!
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components , repeats: true)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notifIdentifier! , content: TaskManager.notification2, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

This is the code for cancelling notifications ...

```
// Deletion of Cells ...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let managedObject: NSManagedObject = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    context.delete(managedObject)
    if tableView == TaskTableViews {
    let itemController = TaskManager()
    let nItem: List = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! List
    itemController.nItem = nItem
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [itemController.notifIdentifier!] )
```

When I try to cancel them, they are very hit and miss. I have tested the code by changing the identifier to a regular String and everything works as it should so its definitely the unique identifier.

Any thoughts/ suggestions on creating a unique ID for every new task/notification?

Comment: What's the problem? What does "they are very hit and miss" even _mean?_ Explain what the issue is, please. What is a TaskManager, anyway?

Comment: Only one notification can be cancelled at a time (not multiple). If you schedule a notification, close the app, then later reopen the app to delete the task, the notification isn't cancelled. Like I said this all works perfectly with a String but using a unique ID is my problem. Im looking for another way to create unique IDs for each task.

Comment: "all works perfectly with a String but using a unique ID is my problem" I can't figure out what that means either. The identifier _is_ a String, so I don't get what distinction you are drawing. And you have not shown how your identifiers are created and stored, so who knows what you're doing? The entire question, so far, is completely unclear (to me at least).

Comment: OK to create a unique string, I am using TaskManager.notification2.userInfo.description as String! instead of making up a String such as "Whatever" for the UNNotifcationRequest

Comment: But you have not shown what a TaskManager is. Why should I believe that `TaskManager.notification2.userInfo.description as String!` generates the _same_ identifier both when you create the notification and later when you try to cancel it?

Comment: The question was, "creating a unique identifier for notifications" not can you critique my code. Next time try answering the question instead of critiquing code. If you can't answer the question, move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduling notifications

```
@IBAction func scheduleNotification(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let uuid = UUID().uuidString


    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Example", arguments: nil)
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    //...

    var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: self.datePicker.date)
    dateComponents.second = 0

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuid, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in

        if let errorPerforms = error {
         print(errorPerforms.localizedDescription)
        } else {
         print("Success")
        }
    }


    let managedObject = ManagedObject(context: self.managedObjectContext!)
    managedObject.setValue(uuid, forKey: "uuid")
    //...

    do {
     try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        self.dimiss()
    } catch {}
}
```

Delete notifications from the `indexPath`.

```
 // Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch editingStyle {
    case .delete:

        let managedObject = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        self.managedObjectContext.delete(managedObject)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [managedObject.uuid!])
        center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [managedObject.uuid!])

        do {
         try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } catch {}

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

This works well! When you're using the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol methods. Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Can I contact you to discuss it further?

Comment: Ok! How I can help you?